# How to make observation a string in custom PyEnvironment

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

In the [tensorflow documentation for TF-Agents Environments](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/2_environments_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=9HD0cDykPL6I&line=5&uniqifier=1) there is an example of an environment for a simple (blackjack inspired) card game.

The `__init__` looks like the following:

```
class CardGameEnv(py_environment.PyEnvironment):

  def __init__(self):
    self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='action')
    self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(1,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, name='observation')
    self._state = 0
    self._episode_ended = False
```

But what if my observation can't be expressed as a number but needs a string? I can't simply specify `dtype=str` or `dtype=pd.str` because of the min/max attributes:

```
TypeError: Cannot find minimum value of <dtype: 'string'> with type <dtype: 'string'>.
  In call to configurable 'BoundedArraySpec' (<class 'tf_agents.specs.array_spec.BoundedArraySpec'>)
```

Anyone got any ideas?